Vite project not loading in the browser, Showing blank page
When i try to run my vite project using npm run dev I get blank white page.
There is no elements or consoles can be seen. I could see status code (304) not modified.
-Tried clearing browser cache.
-Tried changing configuration of vite.js adding.```
server: {
host: true,
port: 8000,
hmr: {
host: 'localhost'
}
}
-Index.html file is in root directory.

-I expect to load my page normally run my vite project properly.


The problem was likely due to nesting the component inside the same component.
Errors like this will lead to load the component infinite times which crashes the file.
Remove nested component inside the same component. And the problem is solved.
